# Why is my css showing ���?

Tags: css, apache, flask, https, character-encoding

> System details:
>   Server: Apache, Ubuntu 16.02
>   Client: Windows 10, Chrome

My apache config file looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName mycoolsiteA.mydomain.com
       ServerAlias mycoolsiteB.mydomain.com

       Alias /static /var/www/python/mysite/static
       Alias /templates /var/www/python/mysite/templates

       WSGIDaemonProcess my_app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/python/mysite/start.py
       WSGIScriptReloading On

       <Directory /var/www/python/mysite>
               WSGIProcessGroup my_app
               WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
               order deny,allow
               Allow from all
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I load the css in a browser it is showing the following. However, this is quite random. It "sometimes" works, and sometimes does not.

My example url is this:
https://mycoolsiteA.mydomain.com/static/css/bs/bootstrap.min.css

We do have a Firewall appliance which auto-redirects http to https, but I'm loading the css directly with https.

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Yet, if I refresh several times, or add a r=number on the end, it will clear the cache and load. But, it will do it again randomly until I clear the cache again.

Here it is loaded and working:

[image]

Any thoughts, direction on where to look to fix this?

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Maybe there is something of interest on the server-side going on.

Comment: @jdv I looked at the apache logs and nothing. Not even a hint to an error, or anything that would cause this.

Comment: check the character encoding of your raw CSS file. Ensure it is UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: check your HTTP server is providing the correct headers of the CSS files

Comment: Does your CSS contain unicode?

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>` when accessing via HTTPS this won't apply.

Comment: @Martin https is handled via the firewall. So that's why it's setup like this

Comment: try chaging `:80` to `:443` and see if it helps. Also clear your browser history too.

Comment: What does the source code of the CSS file look like? I think the issue is yur HTTPS firewall somehow....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the fun world of UTF-8!

I've seen this dozens of times in PHP (see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)). What you're experiencing is almost certainly a UTF-8 file being delivered as some other character encoding (or vice-versa). I downloaded Bootstrap and Notepad++ identifies them as ANSI encoded. Your web server might be forcing that to use UTF-8. Look at the response headers for something like this

```
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
```

So your web server is saying it's UTF-8 but it's really not. At which point your browser starts vomiting out `�`, meaning it doesn't recognize the character.

There's a couple of ways to deal with this if that's the case.

1. Re-encode the file as UTF-8 ([Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do this for you)
2. Stop passing a default UTF-8. Your browser will try to identify the encoding

Just for kicks, try [loading the CSS directly from the MaxCDN servers](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

They do not pass a UTF-8 header